# How can I efficiently implement multithreading/multiprocessing in a Python web bot?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Let's say I have a web bot written in python that sends data via POST request to a web site. The data is pulled from a text file line by line and passed into an array. Currently, I'm testing each element in the array through a simple for-loop. How can I effectively implement multi-threading to iterate through the data quicker. Let's say the text file is fairly large. Would attaching a thread to each request be smart? What do you think the best approach to this would be?

```
with open("c:\file.txt") as file:
     dataArr = file.read().splitlines()

dataLen = len(open("c:\file.txt").readlines())-1

def test(data):
     #This next part is pseudo code
     result = testData('www.example.com', data)
     if result == 'whatever':
          print 'success'

for i in range(0, dataLen):
    test(dataArr[i])
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of this, but I feel it would cause issues depending on the size of the text file. I know there is software that exists which allows the end-user to specify the amount of the threads when working with large amounts of data. I'm not entirely sure of how that works, but that's something I'd like to implement.

```
import threading

with open("c:\file.txt") as file:
     dataArr = file.read().splitlines()

dataLen = len(open("c:\file.txt").readlines())-1

def test(data):
     #This next part is pseudo code
     result = testData('www.example.com', data)
     if result == 'whatever':
          print 'success'

jobs = []

for x in range(0, dataLen):
     thread = threading.Thread(target=test, args=(dataArr[x]))
     jobs.append(thread)

for j in jobs:
    j.start()
for j in jobs:
    j.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a recipe for `multiprocessing.Pool`

See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def test(num):
    if num%2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_of_datas_to_test = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    p = Pool(4)  # create 4 processes to do our work
    print(p.map(test, list_of_datas_to_test))  # distribute our work
```

Output looks like:

```
[True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Threads are slow in python because of the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). You should consider using multiple processes with the Python `multiprocessing` module instead of threads. Using multiple processes can increase the "ramp up" time of your code, as spawning a real process takes more time than a light thread, but due to the GIL, `threading` won't do what you're after.

[Here](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) and [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing_intro.html) are a couple of basic resources on using the `multiprocessing` module. Here's an example from the second link:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import string

# Define an output queue
output = mp.Queue()

# define a example function
def rand_string(length, output):
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(
                    string.ascii_lowercase
                    + string.ascii_uppercase
                    + string.digits)
               for i in range(length))
    output.put(rand_str)

# Setup a list of processes that we want to run
processes = [mp.Process(target=rand_string, args=(5, output)) for x in range(4)]

# Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()

# Get process results from the output queue
results = [output.get() for p in processes]

print(results)
```

Comment: Lol, this is pretty much Will's answer. He edited my one sentence answer. I guess he doesn't care about getting the credit for it, what a boss.