# Pandas dataframe multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I have a code which I want to use make run parallelly.

```
df1["ColA"] = df.apply(lambda rows: func(rows[0], rows[1], row[2]), axis=1)
df1["ColB"] = df.apply(lambda rows: func(rows[0], rows[3], row[4]), axis=1)
df1["ColC"] = df.apply(lambda rows: func(rows[0], rows[5], row[6]), axis=1)
```

This is the part of the code. there are more than 100k rows in the dataframe df and each operation of the func takes a lot of time, so I want to parallelize the task.

Now, I'm working on jupyter notebook (as a part of anaconda 2) and whatever code for multi-threading I've tried have failed. As examples, I tried using [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977245/how-can-i-efficiently-implement-multithreading-multiprocessing-in-a-python-web-b) among a few others, but all of these examples get stuck on both windows and linux.

Can someone please help.

--

Edit: one of the error message I get on windows is

> AttributeError: 'module has no attribute 'rand_string'

Comment: If knowledge of Pandas is necessary, you may want to consider adding a tag for it.

Comment: I'll add the tag but I dont think knowledge of pandas is necessary as there is little to be changed from the pandas point of view.

Comment: There probably is a much better solution than to run this with the multiprocessing module. Post your dataframe and a  dataframe with the desired outcome and its possible that a vectorized implementation can be found.

Comment: @TedPetrou as far as the dataframe is concerned, it is just this. I load a data from a file using read_table command, run the 3 lines above and return the dataframe df1. Thats it.